# In java, how to call the constructor of the instance creator of the current class?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class say 'A', an object 'a' of which creates an object 'b' of class'B'. Now 'b' runs a method which wants to create a new instance of b's parent(please dont confuse it with inheritance) - the class which created 'b', which is 'A' as in here.

Is this anyhow possible in Java ? Or maybe some design suggestion may work.

Thanks !

**Edit : As per suggestions, I am adding my design requirement too. I have an "ExitController" class, which works differently as per the caller function - like if it is invoked by a UserX, it terminates program, if it is invoked by a UserY it logs him off, etc. 
Typically I should be placing an ExitController method in my User interface, but there are some constraints due to which I cant. Also, passing the parent object/classname is seeming very expensive compared to the use it offers.**

Comment: This sounds very strange, maybe you should rethink your design. Maybe you need a factory class.

Comment: A design suggestion might be a very good idea if we actually knew what the problem was.  This sounds like a partial solution to something, but it's not clear what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @dobroby is right. In the future, try to elaborate the functional requirement itself rather than asking how to achieve a solution which may not be the right solution after all, per se.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you've to *pass* the parent itself or the parent type into B's constructor. The below example illustrates the last case.

```
class A {
    B b;

    A() { 
        b = new B(getClass());
    }
}

class B {
    Class<?> parentClass;

    B(Class<?> parentClass) {
        this.parentClass = parentClass;
    }

    void createParent() throws Exception {
        Object o = parentClass.newInstance();
    }
}
```

With [generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) you could make it more type safe. But since the functional requirement is not entirely clear, I've left that away.

---

**Update** as per your update, creating instances is pointless. You could just check the class type and handle accordingly. Instead of `createParent()` in above example, do:

```
void exit() {
    if (parentClass == UserX.class) {
        // Terminate program.
    } else if (parentClass == UserY.class) {
        // Logoff user.
    }
}
```

This is however plain ugly. Are you *really* not allowed to add another method to the `User` interface? Otherwise the following would be a better design (called the [*Strategy pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)):

```
interface User {
    void exit();
}

class ExitController {
    void exit(User user) {
        user.exit();
    }
}

class UserX implements User {
    public void exit() {
        // Terminate program.
    }
}

class UserY implements User {
    public void exit() {
        // Logoff user.
    }
}
```

---

As per your last statement:

> *Also, passing the parent object/classname is seeming very expensive compared to the use it offers*

This makes no sense. Have you measured it? Show us the results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think that class `B` would have to store a reference to either object `a` or `A.class`. That would allow `b` to construct a new instance of `A`. The simplest way to to do this would be for `B`'s constructor to take a class argument.